# Many To Many Relationships in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, crud

I have two entities with many to many relationships in my .NET Core project:

Book:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
    public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookPublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        PublicHouses = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
    }

}
```

Publicion House:

```
public class PublicHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }
    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookPublicHouse> Books { get; set; }

    public PublicHouse()
    {
        Books = new Collection<BookPublicHouse>();
    }
}
```

And I create join table:

```
 public class BookPublicHouse
{
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual PublicHouse PublicHouse { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is context class:

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookPublicHouse>()
            .HasKey(bp => new { bp.BookId, bp.PublicHouseId });

    }
}
```

So next I need to create Api's with CRUD operations, but I dont know how to create it. I dont know how to get book include all publicHouses, which this book contains

```
[Route("api/books")]
public class BookController : Controller
{
    private LibraryContext _dbContext;


    public BookController(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    //get()
    //get(id)
    //create()
    //update
    //delete

}
```

Comment: Additional you need to remove the `virtual` attribute of your DbSets in the LibraryContext.

Answer (score 2):

For Entity Framework *Core*, one usually use `Include()` followed by `ThenInclude` To include "children of children" entities

```
var book = _dbContext.Books
    .Include(b => b.PublicHouses)
    .ThenInclude(bph => bph.PublicHouse)
    .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BookId == 1);
```

(also, be aware that intellisense will trick you into believing this is not correct syntax, until you have written it completely, and sometimes you need to launch a successful build before it stops complaining)